Improve python script runt time deleting files and directories
I have a Python script that deletes files and empty directories older than X days. However, this script is running on a huge directory with millions of files and directories. At the current rate, it will take approximately six weeks to complete the deletion process (looking at disk space metric).
It appears that the main bottleneck is in listing the files and directories. Could anyone suggest code changes or optimizations that can help reduce the runtime?
Not sure it's relevant but for context this run as Job in k8s so resources are not an issue.
def delete_files(root_directory, delete_time_threshold):
    global EXAMINED_FILES
    global DELETED_FILES
    try:
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_directory):
            for file in filenames:
                file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
                try:
                    file_mtime = os.path.getmtime(file_path)
                    EXAMINED_FILES += 1
                    if file_mtime < delete_time_threshold:
                        os.remove(file_path)
                        logging.debug(f"File {file} deleted because mtime {file_mtime} is older than threshold {delete_time_threshold}")
                        DELETED_FILES += 1
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f"Error deleting file {file_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error walking root directory {root_directory}: {e}")

def delete_empty_directories(root_directory, allowed_empty_dirs):
    global EXAMINED_DIRS
    global DELETED_DIRS
    global SKIPPED_DELETE_DIRS
    try:
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_directory):
            if dirpath != root_directory: #don't look at the root directory
                EXAMINED_DIRS += 1
                try:
                    if not dirnames and not filenames:
                        relative_dirpath = re.sub(f'^{root_directory}/', '', dirpath)
                        if relative_dirpath and relative_dirpath in allowed_empty_dirs:
                            logging.debug(f"Skipping deletion of allowed empty directory: {dirpath}")
                            SKIPPED_DELETE_DIRS += 1
                        else:
                            os.rmdir(dirpath)
                            logging.debug(f"Deleted empty directory: {dirpath}")
                            DELETED_DIRS += 1
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f"Error deleting directory {dirpath}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error walking root directory {root_directory}: {e}")



Thank you!

Not really an answer to your question, but if you might consider stepping away from python this might help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194863/delete-files-older-than-x-days combined with this one https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8430/how-to-remove-all-empty-directories-in-a-subtree

Why does your code have a function for deleting empty directories but you say nothing about this in your text? Is that part of your question? How do you call these functions? Do you often call both functions? If yes, you could cut the runtime roughly in half by combining them.

You can use multiprocessing, which will speed up the process.
import os
import logging
import re
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing

EXAMINED_FILES = 0
DELETED_FILES = 0
EXAMINED_DIRS = 0
DELETED_DIRS = 0
SKIPPED_DELETE_DIRS = 0


def process_file(file_path, delete_time_threshold):
    global EXAMINED_FILES
    global DELETED_FILES
    try:
        file_mtime = os.path.getmtime(file_path)
        EXAMINED_FILES += 1
        if file_mtime < delete_time_threshold:
            os.remove(file_path)
            logging.debug(f"File {file_path} deleted because mtime {file_mtime} is older than threshold {delete_time_threshold}")
            DELETED_FILES += 1
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error processing file {file_path}: {e}")


def delete_files(root_directory, delete_time_threshold):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as executor:
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.scandir(root_directory):
            file_paths = [os.path.join(dirpath, file) for file in filenames]
            executor.map(process_file, file_paths, [delete_time_threshold]*len(file_paths))


def delete_empty_directories(root_directory, allowed_empty_dirs):
    global EXAMINED_DIRS
    global DELETED_DIRS
    global SKIPPED_DELETE_DIRS
    try:
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_directory, topdown=False):
            if dirpath != root_directory:
                EXAMINED_DIRS += 1
                try:
                    if not os.listdir(dirpath):
                        relative_dirpath = re.sub(f'^{root_directory}/', '', dirpath)
                        if relative_dirpath and relative_dirpath in allowed_empty_dirs:
                            logging.debug(f"Skipping deletion of allowed empty directory: {dirpath}")
                            SKIPPED_DELETE_DIRS += 1
                        else:
                            os.rmdir(dirpath)
                            logging.debug(f"Deleted empty directory: {dirpath}")
                            DELETED_DIRS += 1
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f"Error deleting directory {dirpath}: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error walking root directory {root_directory}: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root_directory = "/path/to/your/directory"
    delete_time_threshold = 1234567890  # Replace with your actual threshold
    allowed_empty_dirs = set()  # Add your allowed empty directories here

    delete_files(root_directory, delete_time_threshold)
    delete_empty_directories(root_directory, allowed_empty_dirs)

    print(f"Examined files: {EXAMINED_FILES}")
    print(f"Deleted files: {DELETED_FILES}")
    print(f"Examined directories: {EXAMINED_DIRS}")
    print(f"Deleted directories: {DELETED_DIRS}")
    print(f"Skipped allowed empty directories: {SKIPPED_DELETE_DIRS}")

